# How Can I Test An Icon Only Visible On Hover?

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, phpunit

I have a page where a user can edit the title of a form by clicking on a pencil icon only visible on hover. I'm writing a phpunit Selenium test, and I've tried 'MoveToElement' and a few other Selenium functions to access this invisible element, but none are supported yet.

When I try to access the element directly the test errors and outputs

```
    Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

How can I mock a hovered mouse at that icon?

Comment: I'm not sure, and I don't know if I'd understand how to implement them if they were...kinda a noob

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to do it with javascript because none of the other Selenium methods for doing this have php bindings

```
$script_show = 'jQuery(".class_name").css("display", "block");';
$script_hide = 'jQuery(".class_name").css("display", "none");';
//prior to accessing the non-visible element
$this->execute( array( 'script' => $script_show , 'args'=>array() ) );
//after it no longer needs to be visible
$this->execute( array( 'script' => $script_hide , 'args'=>array() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move-to / mouseover / hover / whatever the element that is there when the pencil icon is not visible to get the icon to be visible, then you perform actions on the pencil icon.   How your site's UI is implemented will dictate the exact selenium code once you get the pencil icon to be visible.

Comment: Hover() and mouseover() are not supported by php yet. When using moveto() it errors out and outputs an error of

        PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Exception: Only moving over an element is supported. Please pass a PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element instance.

when using $this->moveto( $this->byXPath( $pencil_xpath ) )